# Why does my character array not print immediately unless I use '\n'?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to print out a character array (carefully choosing my words here) as if it were being typed by someone to the console. For some reason, `printf` does not immediately print the character to the console. As-is, the program will have nothing printed to the console for the exact amount of time taken to print the entire character array. However, when I uncomment the line  `//printf("\n");`  , the console will actually show the contents being "typed", although vertically. In other words, using a newline seems to force the console to immediately print the character.

Why is this, and what would be an ideal way to fix this? I ask because I'm trying to think generally: what if I were writing a text-engine for a graphical video game?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void milliDelay(unsigned int milliseconds)
{
    usleep(milliseconds * 1000);
}

void printConsole(char* txt)
{
    //Define local variables such as the iterator and timers
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned const int keyDelay = 75, puncDelay = 1000;

    //Print each character to the screen until we reach the null character
    for(i = 0; txt[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(txt[i] == '.' || txt[i] == '!' || txt[i] == '?')
        {
            printf("%c", txt[i]);
            milliDelay(puncDelay);
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("%c", txt[i]);
            milliDelay(keyDelay);
        }
        //printf("\n");
    }
    //Newline for much more appealing text formatting
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printConsole("Hello. This is a test using punctuation! Does this pause correctly?");
    return 0;
}
```

For what it's worth, I'm using an Ubuntu system. I have not been able to see if the code works as intended on other platforms. I have also researched this question. I have written the code as *I* thought of it. Others have used `putchar()`, but this is something I never saw in my C programming class--hence I don't use that here. Is there anything bad about using `printf()` over `putchar()` in such a case?

Comment: The characters are not displayed because stdout is a buffered device. So when printf writes characters to stdout, they are buffered and not displayed until a \n character is output, or when the buffer is flushed. If you call fflush(stdout), it will output the characters in the buffer immediately.

Comment: `printf()` is stdout, by default stdout is line buffered.In that case, you need to flush the stdout.

Comment: printf is buffered by default, change this using setvbuf or flush it when needed. Using printf takes more time then using putchar for a single char because print needs to parse its format string at least.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Check the output of a simple `printf("Hello World\n");` with a modern compiler like gcc. Chances are good you will not find a call to `printf` at all, but `puts`! What we learn from this: Leave optimisations to the compiler unless you **really** have a problem and fond the true hot-spots by profiling!